# How can I get body of markdown with Frontmatter?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, astrojs

I want to get the data of the body of my markdown file using the front matter but it is showing undefined, what shall I do to resolve the error?

```
{latest.map(({ url, frontmatter }) => (
<PostCard url={url} content={frontmatter.body}/>
))}
```

Answer (score 3):

See the [Exported Properties](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/#exported-properties) section of the markdown guide in the docs.

`frontmatter.body` is not part of the list, instead you should use `compiledContent()` or `rawContent()` on the imported markdown object.

```js
{latest.map(post => (
<PostCard url={post.url} content={post.compiledContent()} />
))}
```

---

### Full example

When you have *src/pages/posts/a.md*, *src/pages/posts/b.md*, etc.

The following shows all files compiled contents successfully:

*src/pages/index.astro*

```js
---
const posts = await Astro.glob('./posts/*.md')
---

<ul>
    {posts.map(post=>
    <li set:html={post.compiledContent()} />)}
</ul>
```

Comment: Here is the error that I am getting while using your code

Error screenshot - https://imgur.com/a/X2qIFRu Code snippet - https://jsfiddle.net/a09e48uj/

Comment: @DhairyaShah please see my extended answer. I added a full example. It is working for me. If it does not work for you, please share a little more details of your source code.